# opening multiple URI's intent

Tags: android

I have some URI's in a arraylist file(the amount of URI's vary)

And i would like to open them to dispay for the user

currently my intent code looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + selectedItems.get(0)), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

but this obviously only get's the first URI, is there any way to parse multiple URI's?

if not i would love a pointer at the best alternative to show multiple URI's

Comment: And what should happen? Showing multiple images?

Comment: yeah, that's the idea. I'm not sure why i'm getting downvoted, i honestly can't find the answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to parse multiple URI's?

Not for `ACTION_VIEW` or most `Intent` actions. `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` is one of the few actions that supports multiple items as part of the core protocol.

> if not i would love a pointer at the best alternative to show multiple URI's

Write your own UI for it.

Comment: Okay great, just what I wanted to know! Thanks a lot